# How to install pgAdmin 4 on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, postgresql, apt-key

I'm running Linux Mint 19 Tara, and trying to follow the instructions [here](https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/bionic-pgdg/Release) with the goal of installing pgAdmin4 as a desktop app. There seems to be a problem involving the authentication of the repository.

The apt-key step seems to work, as I observe `PostgreSQL Debian Repository` in the apt-key list.

I don't have a `deb` command (I imagine this is a Mint vs Ubuntu difference?), so I used
`add-apt-repository http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ tara-pgdg main`
instead, after which I observe
`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic main`
in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`.

At this point running either `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get update` shows an error
`The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

How can I proceed? It seems unlikely that there really isn't a release file; I can see what looks like an authentication list at [https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/bionic-pgdg/](https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/bionic-pgdg/Release). Do I have a path wrong or something?

Comment: Queued by @sabbir-ahmed's answer, I see that the problem was that `tara-pgdg` in the `add-apt-repository` command was getting mapped to or replaced by `bionic`; it should have been `bionic-pgdg`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open terminal and type:

   ```
    wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Open Software Sources and click on "Additional repositories" and paste the following for Linux Mint 19 (it's based on Ubuntu Bionic):

   ```
    deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
   ```

   or the following for Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu Focal Fossa):

   ```
    deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
   ```

it should look like this:
[image]

Press "OK" and that will automatically update cache.

3. Now open terminal and type the following:

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install pgadmin4
   ```

That should install pgadmin4.

Comment: I get `malformed input, repository not added` when I do this on Mint 19.1. Instead, I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) inserting `bionic` to replace `stretch` in the example given.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Use URL for repo from here..

Comment: for mint 18 I had to use xenial instead of bionic

Comment: Would this work on Linux mint 20?

Comment: A word of caution: I copied the repository URL from this post. However, by accident the copied string included a leading whitespace. When that happens, the Software Sources will complain about the "malformed URL". Be sure to copy the string *exactly*.

Comment: didnt work for me on linux mint 19. got error `malformed input` when using `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main`

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me in Linux Mint 19.1 modified from [docs](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) because my machine had `$(lsb_release -cs)` returning `tessa` which was not working but `bionic` was working.

## Setup the repository

## Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):

curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

## Create the repository configuration file:

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

## Install pgAdmin

## Install for both desktop and web modes:

sudo apt install pgadmin4

Comment: I used "focal" instead of "bionic" for Linux Mint 20.x.

Answer (score 1):

**Python approach always work**

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/lib/pgadmin
$ sudo chown $USER /var/log/pgadmin
$ python3 -m venv pgadmin4
$ source pgadmin4/bin/activate
(pgadmin4) $ pip install pgadmin4

(pgadmin4) $ pgadmin4
```

or

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal/ pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used the second set of instructions and finally got pgadmin4 installed on my computer.